# Tweet and send to WhatsApp from textarea content in simple JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea

Need a help in tweeting and sending to Whatsapp from textarea content in Simple JavaScript. Is there any workaround?

**Here is the Code example for sharing it on Whatsapp. :**
**JS:**

```
function new_share()
{
    var whatsapp_content = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if(whatsapp_content!=='')
    {
       whatsapp_link = 'via Editor  ';

      var url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text="+ whatsapp_content + whatsapp_link;
      document.getElementById('whatsapp_link').setAttribute("href",url);
     }
}
```

**HTML:**

Textarea id: myInput

```
<a id="whatsapp_link" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" onclick="new_share()">Share on WhatsApp
```

I tried, with tweet button provided by twitter. It is not working.

**Example for Tweet:**

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you've tried to do, and what the button provided that you claim doesn't work looks like.

Comment: Double-check line 37.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send a request to Twitter API, but you need to put your request in the backend to hide your credentials.

You can see the Twitter API doc:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update

Comment: Thanks @joão-pedro.
I want to send a tweet via tweet URL instead of API. 
Is it possible?

Comment: yes, is possible make a url link like the whatsapp. you can put the url:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=

with the message in url encode. Example:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=the%20max%20lenght%20is%20228%20characters